# SQL remove duplicate rows in the same table based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a table "monthly" which contains the column "filename", "sheetname", "project", "task", "owner", "hours", "percentage"

```
+---------+---------+--------+----------+-------+------+------------+
|fielname |sheetname|project | task     | owner | hours|percentage  |
+---------+---------+--------+----------+-------+------+-------------+
| file1   | IBM     | Website | develop | sam   |  5   |25
| file1   | IBM     | website | test    | sam   |  7   |20
| file1   | IBM     | support | design  | ivan  |  2   |7                
| file1   | DELL    | android | config  | peter |  9   |30               
| file2   | IBM     | Website | develop | sam   |  9   |45               
| file2   | DELL    | android | config  | josef |  4   |50                
| file2   | DELL    | android | config  | peter |  3   |70               
| file2   | DELL    | android | test    | mark  |  8   |70                
| file2   | HP      | webapp  | code    | jack  |  10  |65 
| file3   | IBM     | website | test    | sam   |  7   |20
| file3   | HP      | webapp  | code    | jack  |  10  |65
| file4   | IBM     | Website | develop | sam   |  9   |45
```

i want to remove the duplicated rows when the sheetname and project and task and owner and hours and percentage is the same between 2 rows just the filename is different so we remove the second row and we keep the first row.

example :

```
| file1   | IBM     | Website | develop | sam   |  5   |25
| file2   | IBM     | Website | develop | sam   |  9   |45 
| file4   | IBM     | Website | develop | sam   |  9   |45
```

fil1 and file2 have different values in hours and percentage so we keep it.
file2 and file4 has the same values in the other column so we remove the entire row where is file4

thank you for your help

Comment: PL/SQL or MySQL?  Please use only one database tag.

Comment: How to decide which one should be picked? file1 and file3 for instance

Comment: If it's Oracle DB, you can use either `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK` analytic functions.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  mysql

Comment: @Jorge Campos  always pick up the first row in case of duplication and remove the last

Comment: The desired result base on your rules `when the sheetname and project and task and owner and hours and percentage is the same between 2 rows` for the file1 for instance the task column changes still you remove some that should be on the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it using tSQL but I'm sure it will be very similar to other permutations of SQL:

Sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #temp;

CREATE TABLE #temp
                  (
             fielname VARCHAR(20), sheetname VARCHAR(20), project VARCHAR(20), task VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20), hours VARCHAR(20), percentage VARCHAR(20)
                  );

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
       ('file1', 'IBM', 'Website', 'develop', 'sam', '5', '25'
       ),
       ('file1', 'IBM', 'website', 'test', 'sam', '7', '20'
       ),
       ('file1', 'IBM', 'support', 'design', 'ivan', '2', '7'
       ),
       ('file1', 'DELL', 'android', 'config', 'peter', '9', '30'
       ),
       ('file2', 'IBM', 'Website', 'develop', 'sam', '9', '45'
       ),
       ('file2', 'DELL', 'android', 'config', 'josef', '4', '50'
       ),
       ('file2', 'DELL', 'android', 'config', 'peter', '3', '70'
       ),
       ('file2', 'DELL', 'android', 'test', 'mark', '8', '70'
       ),
       ('file2', 'HP', 'webapp', 'code', 'jack', '10', '65'
       ),
       ('file3', 'IBM', 'website', 'test', 'sam', '7', '20'
       ),
       ('file3', 'HP', 'webapp', 'code', 'jack', '10', '65'
       ),
       ('file4', 'IBM', 'Website', 'develop', 'sam', '9', '45'
       );
```

Show sample data:

```
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

[image]

Removing duplicates using Common Table Expression and Windowing function with `ROW_NUMBER()` assuming we do not use filename field in the `PARTITION BY` windowing function

```
;WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT     #temp.fielname, 
             #temp.sheetname, 
             #temp.project, 
             #temp.task, 
             #temp.owner, 
             #temp.hours, 
             #temp.percentage , 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #temp.sheetname, 
                                       #temp.project, 
                                       #temp.task, 
                                       #temp.owner, 
                                       #temp.hours, 
                                       #temp.percentage 
                            ORDER BY       #temp.fielname, 
                                       #temp.sheetname, 
                                       #temp.project, 
                                       #temp.task, 
                                       #temp.owner, 
                                       #temp.hours, 
                                       #temp.percentage)  AS rn
      FROM #temp)

      DELETE FROM CTE WHERE rn>1
```

Data set without duplicates

```
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

[image]